# history.replace() not working in auth0 class and react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, auth0, history.js

history.replace() not working in auth0 class

```
//src/history.js

import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Then I am trying to import this into my Auth0 class to use history.replace(). these are two of the functions from the class and how I am trying to use this function.

```
//components/Auth.js

handleAuthentication() {
        this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
            if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
                this.setSession(authResult);
            } else if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                alert(`Error: ${err.error}. Check the console for further details.`);

                location.hash = "";
                //location.pathname = "/";
                history.replace("/");
            }
        });
    }

    setSession(authResult) {
        // Set isLoggedIn flag in localStorage
        //localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');

        // Set the time that the access token will expire at
        let expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());

        localStorage.setItem("access_token", authResult.accessToken);
        localStorage.setItem("id_token", authResult.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem("expires_at", expiresAt);

        location.hash = "";
        //location.pathname = "/dashboard";
        history.replace("/dashboard");

    }
```

I am also adding the history as a prop to my router here.

```
<Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Home auth={this.props.auth} {...props} />}/>
                <Route path="/dashboard" render={(props) => <Dashboard auth={this.props.auth} {...props} />}/>
                <Route path="/callback" render={(props) => <Callback auth={this.props.auth} {...props} />}/>
            </Switch>
</Router>
```

I have read to wrap a component with withRouter() but this only seems to work for components and this case I am trying to just use a class.

Answer (score -1):

Are you seeing any errors in the console when running it? This doesn't seem to be directly related to Auth0 and more on the aspect of the prop populating up to the top when called. Thanks!

Comment: you are correct it doesn’t directly relate to Auth0 specifically but more relates to accessing the history from a class that is not a component